# Get circle image from camera

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I am working with custom layout for camera. I should be able create circle "capture" and I should see circle capture in a preview mode. I've created layout with SurfaceView and putted the SurfaceView bacground color as "#CC000000". It is gives me a black backround when I try to get an image via camera - it's cool. 
How can I set center circle and this circle should not be under "#CC000000" color and then get the image from camera ?

[image]

**UPD**: layout code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"
                android:background="@drawable/camera" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Click" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

camera.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#CC000000"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: Can you put the code you have?

Comment: yes, sure. I've updated summary.